# Loops causing JComboBoxes to not be referenced

Tags: java, swing, loops, jcombobox, sudoku

I'm working on a Java code that solves a Sudoku puzzle. The logic has not been implemented yet, but I have run into a problem with using loops to create my JComboBoxes. My code compiles and runs without error, however it only converts the bottom right 3x3 pane into JLabels. I believe the issue is caused by the loops below.

```
for (int boxRow = 0; boxRow<3; boxRow++){
  for(int boxCol = 0; boxCol<3; boxCol++){
    boxes[boxRow][boxCol] = new JPanel();
    boxes[boxRow][boxCol].setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++){
      for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++){
        comboBox[row][col] = new JComboBox(sudokuChoose);
        constraints.weightx = 1;
        constraints.weighty = 1;
        constraints.gridx = col;
        constraints.gridy = row;
        boxes[boxRow][boxCol].add(comboBox[row][col], constraints);
      }
    }
    constraints.weightx = 1;
    constraints.weighty = 1;
    constraints.gridx = boxRow;
    constraints.gridy = boxCol;
    add(boxes[boxRow][boxCol], constraints);
    boxes[boxRow][boxCol].setVisible(true);
  }
}


    for(int boxRow = 0; boxRow<3; boxRow++){
  for(int boxCol = 0; boxCol<3; boxCol++){
    labelBoxes[boxRow][boxCol] = new JPanel();
    labelBoxes[boxRow][boxCol].setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++){
      for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++){
        tempComboText = (String)comboBox[row][col].getSelectedItem();
        label[row][col] = new JLabel();
        //System.out.println(comboBox[row][col]);
        //System.out.println((String)comboBox[row][col].getSelectedItem());
        label[row][col].setText(tempComboText);
        constraints.weightx = 1;
        constraints.weighty = 1;
        constraints.gridx = col;
        constraints.gridy = row;
        add(label[row][col], constraints);
        label[row][col].setVisible(true);
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

The first creates 9 JComboBoxes, which are in a JPanel. There are 9 JPanels, creating a total of 81 JComboBoxes. However, when the boxes are being created, the name of each corresponding JComboBox in each JPanel is the same. Therefore, there are no names associated with JComboBoxes in the first 8 JPanels. In the second, I convert the JComboBoxes using the same loop structure used in the first, but since the JComboBoxes in the first 8 JPanels do not have names, they cannot be reached and the information cannot be read from them. Any idea on how I would work around this?

Comment: Array items have no "names". Please consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I agree. Do you have any suggestions on how I can use a loop to create them while retaining their names?

Comment: Richard, I fear that you are ascribing too much importance to variable names. They have little importance. What you need to focus on are object ***references***, and for that the arrays and array indices work perfectly.

Comment: Perhaps I phrased my comment incorrectly. I meant to ask how I could use loops, perhaps a different structure so that the array indices are unique to their references. Right now, after each 3x3 comboBox is created, they are no longer referenced because the same array indices are used for the next set of 3x3.

Comment: The biggest problem for me here is that I am still having difficulty understanding just what your code is trying to do here. Again please consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) that we can compile, run, and modify.